# communicate between iphone and windows pc?

Tags: iphone

I want to write an app to communicate between the iPhone and a Windows pc. Where can I find more information on that particular communication?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet I beleive is to just use the network. If you're doing something nice and simple HTTP might even work for you. If you need to transfer files they NFS or FTP.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following link:
[Bonjour for .net](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/03/bonjour-for-net.html)

I tested the sample app and it communicates with my iPhone. I will digg more in that on the next day or tow and will inform you.

Comment: Cannot find any documentation for that